# When is an enemy "alerted to my presence"?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-battle-warriors-way

Every once in a while, Wentworth tells me that I can't spy on an enemy because they are "alerted to my presence". I've even re-engaged the enemy later (after losing the battle and some soldiers) and been able to spy on them.  How can I know whether I'll be able to spy on an enemy before starting a battle?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the enemy is "alerted" either when the enemy is immune to spying (which you can't tell before you engage them at least once), or you've used up your X spys per battle.